Players.ilippo.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.Storage.Script:15: attempt to index nil with 'Connect'




local proximityprompt = game.Workspace.Tycoons.Tycoon.MainItems.Cardboard_Box.Box.ProximityPrompt
local StorageGui = script.Parent
local x = script.Parent.Storage.Frame.X

local Orebuttons = script.Parent.Storage.Frame.Ores:GetChildren()
local OreString = script.Parent.Parent.Sell.Frame.Ore

proximityprompt.Triggered:Connect(function()

    StorageGui.Visible = true
end)
x.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    StorageGui.Visible = false
end)
Orebuttons.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    print("Click")
    OreString.Value = Orebuttons.Name
end)





I don't know what should I do
I tried making that all buttons in folder will work in 1 line of code, and i didn't think that gonna make me more problems

Hi @Sodz1aX, what question are you asking? I don't think other users will understand what you're trying to do without more details.

It seems like you are getting the children from Orebuttons which returns an array and then connecting to that which returns nil because it is an array and not a button you can connect to.
You need to loop through each button in Orebuttons and then connect to that.
for _, button: GuiButton in pairs(Orebuttons) do
    if button:IsA("GuiButton") then
        button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
            print("Click")
            OreString.Value = button.Name
        end)
    end
end

This code goes through the Orebuttons array and then if the child is a GuiButton then connect MouseButton1Click to that button.
